# Django Multiple AdminSite NoReverseMatch from second AdminSite instance

Tags: django

I am having an odd issue with multiple adminsites.

I have 2 admin sites. One, `unicorn_admin.site`, and the default `django.contrib.admin.site`.

*Some* apps give me a `NoReverseMatch` error when attempting admin reverse urls. Consider the following:

This same template is used for both admin site instances. The code is 100% the same.

```
{% url 'admin:packingslips_packingslipformat_changelist' %}
{# NoReverseMatch from /unicorn/ but okay from /b/ #}
```

I'm under the impression that perhaps the `admin` namespace is set to the currently active admin automatically, so even though I've named my second admin `unicorn_admin`, while rendering a `unicorn_admin` view, the namespace `admin` is set to the `unicorn_admin` instance?

Any ideas appreciated.

#### unicorn_admin.py

```
site = AdminSite(name='unicorn_admin')
```

#### Root URLConf

```
(r'^unicorn/', include(unicorn_admin.site.urls)),
(r'^b/', include(admin.site.urls)),  # direct link to default admin panel
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [namespaces](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces) to add few copies of the same urlconf (in your case - 2 admin sites). In comments we found 2 ways to do different namespaces for different admin sites.

Comment: You want to double namespace? The admin is already namespaced with the admin site name.. you can't set a namespace on an admin include

Comment: `admin.site.urls` is a tuple of `(urlconf, app_name, namespace)`. Use `admin.site.get_urls()` with custom app name and namespace for second admin site.

Comment: ilvar, that works! The docs say the `AdminSite` name parameter becomes the namespace like so: `custom_admin:foo_bar_changelist` so I assumed namespace was not an issue. Can you edit your answer so I can un-downvote you? Thank you :)